# how to define a macro to a macro

Tags: c, macros

I want to define something like this:

`#define IS_PROC_ONE                 defined(SP_PROC_TYPE_ONE)`

or

```
#define IS_PROC_ONE                 （#define ONE 1）
```

Is there any way to do this?

notes: I have try the following codes, it works.

```
#define ONE
#define TWO defined(ONE)


int main()
{
#if TWO
    printf("test success\n");
#endif

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that might be illegal

Comment: But not that we'll call the police...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your two defines are not at all alike. Vote to close for lack of clarity.

Comment: Macro language is not so smart... It guarranteed operates with just one pass, so there is no way to generate preprocessor directives using another one.

Comment: The included example in your question works because the `defined(ONE)` expression evaluates to true as ONE is a macro already defined so the subsequent code is included and executed , try removing the definition of `ONE` and you will see that nothing is printed just because the value of `TWO` ain't `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a macro in other macro.

According to C99 section (6.10.3.4 #2)

> If any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being
>   replaced, it is not replaced. These nonreplaced macro name
>   preprocessing tokens are no longer available for further replacement
>   even if they are later (re)examined in contexts in which that macro
>   name preprocessing token would otherwise have been replaced.

Further in ( #3)

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence
>   is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one

One way which I think can work is this :

```
#define ONE 1
#define IS_PROC_ONE ONE
```

Comment: But, when I try #define IS_PROC_ONE defined(SP_PROC_TYPE_ONE), it works on my machine.

Comment: @wilsonwen Which compiler you use it must be GNU because it treats `defined` operator normally a genuine one , try to use `-pedantic` in command line option and this will show you warning ... as per C standard `defined` operator appearing as a macro expansion is considered undefined behavior , but some compiler may accept it.

Comment: @wilsonwen Excuse me ! what I meant from my first comment is that gnu treats defined operator as a macro expansion normally :)

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers here are correct, it's better to ensure that `TWO` is defined no matter what when using it with `#if` (there are compiler flags which will throw up warnings when you check an undefined macro). Why? Because it might be a typo. Maybe you wrote `#if TWOO` by mistake.

```
#ifdef ONE
#define TWO 1
#else
#define TWO 0
#endif
```

Note that your code doesn't actually work. Try removing the line which defines ONE and you'll see that `if TWO` is still considered true. That's because `TWO` is set to `defined(ONE)` (the text).

As far as extending this to put a define statement in a macro, you can't. As noted by others, the pre-processor evaluates tokens *once* (although it will expand tokens many times, by some rather odd rules). There is probably another way to achieve your end result. If you post more code I'll update this answer.

Comment: On removing the line defining `ONE` the `defined(ONE)` expression's value becomes `0` it only evaluates to true if the `ONE` is defined as a macro but when you remove the line you remove the definition so `test success` is not printed.

Comment: @PHIfounder actually it's a bit more subtle than that; it seems that it's only further expanded in the `#if`: http://codepad.org/lw6PnJab but you're right that it actually does work. It's very bizarre behaviour and I'd hate to have to maintain anybody's code which does this.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually impossible since the preprocessor goes in one pass the second `#define` or third if you wanna be that crazy will not be found by the preprocessor.

You can however call macros inside other macros if that helps solve your problem

you can also do something like

```
#ifdef BLAHBLABH
#define WHATEVER
#endif
```

This conditionally defines `WHATEVER`

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it the way you outlined it however you can do it as following:

```
#if defined(SP_PORC_TYPE_ONE)
#define IS_PROC_ONE
#endif
```